# Excel - getting a range from a list

Tags: microsoft-excel, range

How can I get a list of ranges that belong to a certain value.
Example, how to go from this:

| Value | Id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | a |
| 3 | a |
| 4 | b |
| 5 | b |
| 6 | a |
| 7 | a |
| 8 | b |
| 9 | a |
| 10 | c |

to:

| Range | Id |
| --- | --- |
| 1-3,6-7,9 | a |
| 4-5,8 | b |
| 10 | c |

or:

| Range | Id |
| --- | --- |
| 12,3,6,7,9 | a |
| 4,5,8 | b |
| 10 | c |

I realize I could use a filter but that hides the values that are intertwined in the middle of another range.

Comment: Welcome! Does your version of Excel have a [**TEXTJOIN() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c)? In this case, a simple array formula of the form `{=TEXTJOIN(",";1;IF($B$2:$B$11="a";$A$2:$A$11;""))}` will solve the problem.

Comment: Thats really good! I think it should be easy to go over it once more and create the "1-3" where its can be done. Thank you. If you please would comment Ill mark it solved.

Comment: If it were not about Excel, but about [**LibreOffice Calc**](https://www.libreoffice.org/), then I could immediately offer a ready-made solution - [**ListOK**](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/5118): `{=LSTARR(IF($B$2:$B$11="a";$A$2:$A$11&", ";""))}` return **1-3, 6, 7, 9**

Comment: Another variation is to use: `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTER($A$1:$A$10,$B$1:$B$10=B13))` assuming the criteria are in B13, B14 and B15.

Comment: Excel is where I have the data but quite honestly I will use whatever works best. Including placing everything on a db and SQL. I have some limited experience there.

Answer (score 1):

**ID** column enter the formula:

```
=UNIQUE(B2:B11)
```

[image]

**Value** column enter the formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER($A$2:$A$11,$B$2:$B$11=F2))
```

[image]