# How to transpose data (pivot table?) so that I get a single row for each type of element - summing different variant of that

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

here is example data I have, and a result I want to get:

[excel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0bX3.png)

| Name | Amount | Material |
| --- | --- | --- |
| W01 | 100 | AA |
| W01 | 100 | BB |
| Z01 | 200 | CC |
| Z02 | 15 | AA |
| Z02 | 150 | BB |
| Z02 | 350 | DD |
| Z02 | 15 | EE |

| Name | Layers |
| --- | --- |
| W01 | AA 100_BB 100 |
| Z01 | CC 200 |
| Z02 | AA 15_BB 150_DD 350 |

Basically how to make a table where each name is single row and the cell next to it concatenates all different materials? Order does not matter here

Comment: Welcome! Will [**this solution**](https://superuser.com/a/1751508/1586123) work in your version of Excel?

Comment: Indeed, pivot tables are a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula:

```
=LET(
data,$A$2:$C$8,
namecol,INDEX(data,,1),
names,UNIQUE(namecol),
matamt,INDEX(data,,3)&" "&INDEX(data,,2),
lookup,MAP(names,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN("_",TRUE,FILTER(matamt,namecol=x)))),
HSTACK(names,lookup))
```

[image]